# Stupid Question: Multiselecting objects?

Tags: selection-tools

I am working on this animation and just realized that around maybe 2 thousand objects are messed up with sequence of animation so how do I select all those objects? Kinda like Photoshop selection tool

Comment: Hi, welcome, There are so many ways...  open the "select" menu in the 3d view... and add to that 1) manual selection is by right click 2) it can be extended using SHIFT. To have better suggestions, maybe share some more detail on the scene composition, and/or a meaningful picture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selection Brush:
You could use the selection brush of Blender with the <kbd>C</kbd> shortcut. To select use the Left mouse button and to deselect use the middle mouse button. Use the mouse wheel to increase the size of the cursor. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to confirm the selection

Selection Brush:

[image: Secelection Brush]

Lasso Selection Tool:
Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click and drag over your items. Let go of Left mouse button to confrim the selection

Lasso Tool:

[image: Lasso]

Also you could do like the user m.ardito said using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to select mulptiple objects. Also if it's easier select all objects with <kbd>A</kbd> and deselect the objects you don't need to affect. Otherwise you could select of the of the right objects and invert your selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!!! Just saved me hours of work

Comment: Glad I could help, which technique did you use by the way

Comment: The selection tool(C)